# How do I use playerprefs to make ui slider keep the sound settings?

Tags: unity, c#, scripting, unityscript

I have not use playerprefs before, I want to know how to keep the change of the audio when the player change it throughout the game.

Answer (score 1):

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SliderSaver : MonoBehaviour {

    public Slider slider;

    void Awake ()
    {
        slider.Value = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("Slider value");
    }

    public void OnSliderChange (float newValue)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("Slider value", newValue);
    }

}
```

This sets the slider's value in the beginning to the saved value then changes that saved value whenever the slider changes.

Comment: It pop-up an error,error

 CS1061: Type `Slider' does not contain a definition for `Value' and no extension method `Value' of type `Slider' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Make sure you use UnityEngine.UI to interact with the UI through script. Check out the answer edit.

Comment: Shouldn't you define a default value in GetFloat, for when you access it the first time before it has been set?

Comment: Yeah, if you'd like to.

Comment: This is heading in the right direction, but the code sample could be improved. There's no OnSliderChange MonoBehaviour call in Unity 5 (maybe you're thinking of NGUI?), so you may need to attach a listener to slider.onValueChanged to call this. The "Slider value" key should be a public string property (along with the default value as jhocking mentions above), so this class can be re-used to save multiple slider values, with the developer free to change their keys/defaults in the inspector. You should also look at clamping the value from PlayerPrefs to a valid range, since it's user-editable.

Comment: I'm not sure OnSliderChange was ever a callback. You're supposed to choose the method to call in the inspector in the slider's settings. Honestly, I'm not trying to write a game for the asker. This is just answering a simple question.